# Pros/Cons of the following code with Autofac DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I had a discussion with my boss on DI pattern in C# and I would like to get some reviews and discussion on the following code snippets.

Key points to look into is that the instantiation of the `ExternalService` and `ExternalServiceConfig` where there's no interface for DI to register or mock.

**Pattern A** - Instantiate the `ExternalServiceConfig` and assign all the required values then create an instance of `ExternalService` by passing `ExternalServiceConfig` into its constructor right in `ExternalServiceWrapper`.

**Pattern B** - Register both `ExternalServiceConfig` and `ExternalService` into the DI Container then inject an instance of `ExternalService` into `ExternalServiceWrapper`

### Questions

- What are the pros/cons of both `Pattern A` and `Pattern B`?
- Which one is the "more" recommended way of implementing/registering the external libraries out of these patterns?
- Any alternatives, suggestions are welcome

## Pattern A

```
using Autofac;
using Module = Autofac.Module;

Console.WriteLine("Pattern A");
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<AutofacModule>();
var container = builder.Build();

await using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
var wrapper = scope.Resolve<IExternalServiceWrapper>();
await wrapper.DoSomethingByWrapper();

internal class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ExternalServiceWrapper>().SingleInstance().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
}

internal interface IExternalServiceWrapper
{
    Task DoSomethingByWrapper();
}

internal class ExternalServiceWrapper : IExternalServiceWrapper
{
    private readonly ExternalService _externalService;

    public ExternalServiceWrapper()
    {
        var config = new ExternalServiceConfig
        {
            // This key is being injected via IOptions<T> and omitted for simplicity
            // Should be something like: `options.Value.Key`
            Key = "A_VERY_LONG_SECRET_KEY_GETTING_VALUE_BY_INJECTING_IOPTIONS"
        };
        _externalService = new ExternalService(config);
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingByWrapper()
    {
        await _externalService.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine("Do some other thing within the wrapper");
    }
}
```

## Pattern B

```
using Autofac;
using Module = Autofac.Module;

Console.WriteLine("Pattern B");
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<AutofacModule>();
var container = builder.Build();

await using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
var wrapper = scope.Resolve<IExternalServiceWrapper>();
await wrapper.DoSomethingByWrapper();

internal class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(e =>
        {
            var options = e.Resolve(IOptions<ExternalServiceConfig>);
            var config = new ExternalServiceConfig
            {
                Key = options.Values.Key
            };
            return config;
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(e =>
        {
            var config = e.Resolve<ExternalServiceConfig>();
            var externalService = new ExternalService(config);
            return externalService;
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<ExternalServiceWrapper>().SingleInstance().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
}

internal interface IExternalServiceWrapper
{
    Task DoSomethingByWrapper();
}

internal class ExternalServiceWrapper : IExternalServiceWrapper
{
    private readonly ExternalService _externalService;

    public ExternalServiceWrapper(ExternalService externalService)
    {
        _externalService = externalService;
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingByWrapper()
    {
        await _externalService.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine("Do some other thing within the wrapper");
    }
}
```

## External Service (For Reference)

These external classes are out of our control.

```
/**** Sample of external service, this part cannot be modified, no interface defined ****/
internal class ExternalService
{
    private readonly ExternalServiceConfig _config;

    public ExternalService(ExternalServiceConfig config) { _config = config; }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Do something from external service: {0}", _config.Key);
    }
}

internal class ExternalServiceConfig { public string Key { get; set; } }
```

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: I'm sorry, if you think it's to broad. However, if you read through what I have in the code it might not be as broad as you think. It's just the way how these 2 patterns instantiate a class. For example, Pattern A is more readable and simple since it instantiate the class directly in the constructor etc.

Answer (score 1):

> *where there's no interface for DI to register or mock*

Why try to figure out a way around the obstacle, instead of figuring out how to remove the obstacle?

Badly designed external libraries can be wrapped in a better wrapper. It sucks that you have to provide the good design wrapper around the library (I would consider *not* using the library if there are better designed alternatives available), but that is still decidedly better than letting the bad design into your codebase internals.

At no point should you be wiring external types directly into your DI container without at least a minimal layer of abstraction shielding you from it (e.g. an interface around a concrete class).

Comment: Totally agreed, however, it's just the way the "external lib" was written. So, I have to basically swallow what I have on hand. Given what I have here, are you saying that Pattern A is better then? Instantiating in the constructor versus registering it into the container and inject into the constructor as Pattern B shows?

Comment: @TaipanPrasithpongchai: ...yes. Your approach is a bit vague on how it could instantiate the library's own classes (e.g. using a builder pattern vs a factory vs just a plain old wrapper) but at the end of the day what I'm suggesting is that you only register interfaces in your container. If the library doesn't come with interfaces, then a self-built wrapper with a self-built interface is the next best thing. Honestly, I would suggest you always abstract _all_ your libraries, not just the badly designed ones in particular.

Comment: @TaipanPrasithpongchai: The one exception to "interface only" I tend to make is for config objects (which are plain DTOs with no logic), but I still wouldn't do it if the config object wasn't self-built. Direct dependencies on library types are a form of tight coupling (if not _the_ form) and should be avoided at all turns.

Comment: Got it, let consider the code that I posted, wouldn't `Pattern A` make it so that it tightly couple? Since it's creating an instance in the constructor, whereas `Pattern B` is more loosely because it's registering the `ExternalService` into the DI?

Comment: @TaipanPrasithpongchai: The goal here isn't to loosely couple a wrapper and its wrapped element. A wrapper is _tailor-made_ for what it wraps. By that definition, it's never going to be loosely coupled. The goal here is to not explicitly register any type defined by an external library in your DI container. If you were talking about two normal everyday classes that you built, B would generally be the desired approach. But a wrapper around an external library's class is a different scenario.

Comment: Apologize for not being clear, forget the wrapper. I'm thinking more of how the external lib's instance is being created. See the constructor of both pattern, `Pattern A` instantiate external lib within the constructor. Whereas `Pattern B`, the instance of external lib is being injected into the constructor. Do you prefer creating an instance "new" in the wrapper's constructor or inject into the constructor? Regardless of both ways, the wrapper has to be done. When the wrapper class is used, the instance of the wrapper class will be resolved from DI container `var wrapper = scope.Resolve<IEx`

Comment: @TPBKK _"forget the wrapper"_ is quite orthogonal to what I'm saying. _Generally speaking_, approach B is more desirable as it loosely coupled the component and its dependency. However, that is not the primary goal here. The primary goal of the wrapper is to, very specifically, **avoid explicitly registering the library class into the DI container**. Approach B does the opposite of that, hence why it is to be avoided in this case. In essence, the wrapper takes on the tight coupling, so that the DI container itself doesn't have to.